# Overcommit RailsSchemaUpToDate passes when --run but fails when commit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, ruby-overcommit

I am experiencing a strange issue with `overcommit` and `Rails 5.0.2` app with `ruby 2.4.0` :

```
$ overcommit --run
Running pre-commit hooks
Check if database schema is up to date..........[RailsSchemaUpToDate] OK
Check YAML syntax........................................[YamlSyntax] OK
Check Gemfile dependencies..............................[BundleCheck] OK
Check for vulnerable versions of gems...................[BundleAudit] OK
Analyze with RuboCop........................................[RuboCop] OK
Analyze with haml-lint.....................................[HamlLint] OK

✓ All pre-commit hooks passed
$ git ci -m "Overcommit and Linters added"
Running pre-commit hooks
Check if database schema is up to date..........[RailsSchemaUpToDate] FAILED
It looks like you're adding a migration, but did not update the schema file
Check YAML syntax........................................[YamlSyntax] OK
Check Gemfile dependencies..............................[BundleCheck] OK
Check for vulnerable versions of gems...................[BundleAudit] OK
Analyze with RuboCop........................................[RuboCop] OK
Analyze with haml-lint.....................................[HamlLint] OK

✗ One or more pre-commit hooks failed
```

This is the relevant part of my `Gemfile`:

```
group :lint do
  gem 'overcommit', '~> 0.41', require: false  # hook event pre-commit, pre-push
  gem 'brakeman', '~> 3.7.2', require: false  # A static analysis security vulnerability scanner
  gem 'haml-lint', '~> 0.26', require: false  # Syntax checker for HAML
  gem 'ruby_css_lint', '~> 0.1', require: false  # Syntax checker for CSS
  gem 'rubocop', '~> 0.50', require: false  # A Ruby static code analyzer
  gem 'bundler-audit', '~> 0.6'  # Check dependencies
end
```

In my `.overcommit.yml` I have:

```
PreCommit:
  ALL:
    exclude:
      - 'bin/**'
      - 'public/**'
      - 'vendor/**'
  # ...

  # Migration Check
  RailsSchemaUpToDate:
    enabled: true
    on_warn: fail
```

My db folder structure is:

```
+-- db
| +-- seeds.rb
| +-- migrate
  | +-- 20170922082256_devise_create_users.rb
  | +-- 20170922084050_create_fans.rb
| +-- schema.rb
```

This is the relevant part of my `db/schema.rb`:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170922084050) do
# ...
end
```

I tried to downgrade to `ruby 2.3.1` but I am still experiencing the same issue.

Is someone experiencing the same issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out actually.
It seems that `overcommit --run` runs against the full project (except for changes not staged for commit), while the Pre-Commit hook is triggered only on changes to be committed.

I added all the linters in that commit, I ran `bundle exec rubocop --auto-correct` excluding `db/schema.rb` in my `.rubocop.yml` for all cops.

This caused the presence of `migration_files` (previous migration files edited) with no `schema_files` (no change was made on `schema.rb`), so:

```
if migration_files.any? && schema_files.none?
```

was found an raised the error as per the [source linked by Brian](https://github.com/brigade/overcommit/blob/master/lib/overcommit/hook/pre_commit/rails_schema_up_to_date.rb#L8).

For that reason, I just committed disabling overcommit and, from the next commit on, this error did not reproduce anymore

```
$ OVERCOMMIT_DISABLED=1 git ci -m "Overcommit and Linters added"
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe the difference is that `overcommit --run` is looking at what's already been committed to master, while the pre-commit hook is looking at what you're trying to commit.

Looking at [the source](https://github.com/brigade/overcommit/blob/master/lib/overcommit/hook/pre_commit/rails_schema_up_to_date.rb), the error message you're getting is shown when  `if migration_files.any? && schema_files.none?` is true. That is, there are files under `db/migrate/`, but no `db/schema.rb` file.

Can you show the output of `git status`? Maybe your `db/schema.rb` file got deleted somehow?