# Rails: "overcommit --run" is passing but pre-commit hooks fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git-commit, pre-commit-hook, rubocop, ruby-overcommit

I am experiencing an issue with pre-commit hooks in `overcommit`, which is configured to run `rubocop` and `rails_best_practices`.

In short, all three commands listed below passed but `overcommit` wouldn't let me commit to git. Any advice on why/how to circumvent this issue would be appreciated.

```rb
# These passed
rubocop -a
rails_best_practices .
overcommit --run
```

```rb
# Git commit failed
$ overcommit --run
Running pre-commit hooks
Analyze with RailsBestPractices..................[RailsBestPractices] OK
Analyze with RuboCop........................................[RuboCop] OK

✓ All pre-commit hooks passed


$ git commit -m 'Ensure lower case with Attr API'
Running pre-commit hooks
Analyze with RailsBestPractices..................[RailsBestPractices] FAILED
Errors on modified lines:
/Users/USER_NAME/projects/APP_NAME/app/models/lower_case_string.rb:2 - remove unused methods (LowerCaseString#cast)

Analyze with RuboCop........................................[RuboCop] FAILED
Errors on modified lines:
/Users/USER_NAME/projects/APP_NAME/app/models/lower_case_string.rb:3:3: C: Layout/IndentationWidth: Use 2 (not 0) spaces for indentation.

✗ One or more pre-commit hooks failed
```

Now, I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46365031/overcommit-railsschemauptodate-passes-when-run-but-fails-when-commit) that `overcommit --run` doesn't trigger the hooks in the same ways that it does when you actually try to commit (whole project vs only changes to be committed). However, I'm not sure how this would affect my case, especially since `rubocop` and `rails_best_practices` both passed individually as well. By the way, the errors raised here are both false alarms. `rails_best_practices` shouldn't be checking for unused methods in the first place, since that check has been turned off in `config/rails_best_practices.yml`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a few weeks of working with these gems, I think I've figured it out. I'll leave some pointers here for anyone who encounters similar issues.

**1. Stage your changes before doing `overcommit --run` with `git add 
 <file>`**

As this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46365031/overcommit-railsschemauptodate-passes-when-run-but-fails-when-commit?answertab=votes#tab-top) and [docs](https://github.com/sds/overcommit#Usage) say, the `--run` command does not check untracked files.

**2. Add `gemfile` option to `.overcommit.yml`**

One issue I had was that `overcommit` was failing to read my `config/rails_best_practices.yml` (it wasn't supposed to be checking for `unused methods` in the first place, since that check was turned off in the config file).

It seems that when I was trying to `git commit`, `overcommit` was using gems installed in my system (not in the `Gemfile`), and as a result somehow failing to read my config file. So I added the `gemfile` option as recommended in the docs, and made sure `overcommit` uses the `Gemfile`/`bundler` version. I haven't gotten the subject error ever since. As the docs say:

> If you are using Bundler to manage your Ruby gem dependencies, you'll likely want to use the gemfile option to control which gem versions are available during your hook runs.

**My `.overcommit.yml` file for reference:**

```rb
gemfile: Gemfile

PreCommit:
 RuboCop:
   enabled: true
   on_warn: fail

 RailsBestPractices:
   enabled: true
   on_warn: fail
   command: ['bundle', 'exec', 'rails_best_practices', '-c', 'config/rails_best_practices.yml']
```

As a side note - I haven't tried this, but apparently you can also create a separate `Gemfile` just for `overcommit` purposes, if you feel that loading your original `Gemfile` slows down the hook execution ([docs](https://github.com/sds/overcommit/blob/master/config/default.yml)).